# Sumar dos filas en r con una condicional

Tags: r, rstudio, ciencia-de-datos

Tengo un dataframe de las cargas de gasolina de una gasolinera con las siguientes variables: id de la placa, litros de carga de gasolina y la fecha de carga.

Tengo placas que cargan dos veces el mismo día, por ello me gustaría sumar los litros de gasolina que se hicieron en un solo día por cada placa.

```
Id_placa    Fecha   Litros
100007  15/01/2021  12.55
100007  18/01/2021  8.95
100007  18/01/2021  13.77
100007  19/01/2021  10.93
100007  20/01/2021  14.05
100007  21/01/2021  11.23
100007  21/01/2021  12.04
100011  01/01/2021  14.35
100011  01/01/2021  6.85
100011  01/01/2021  10.41
100011  02/01/2021  8.58
100011  02/01/2021  6.1
100011  02/01/2021  8.44
```

Comment: Hola  @Carlos Landverde, por favor pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar partiendo de ello.

Answer (score 1):

Con R base puedes usar `aggregate()` para agrupar por placa y fecha y sumar los litros:

```
aggregate(Litros ~ Id_placa + Fecha, df, sum)

  Id_placa      Fecha Litros
1   100011 01/01/2021  31.61
2   100011 02/01/2021  23.12
3   100007 15/01/2021  12.55
4   100007 18/01/2021  22.72
5   100007 19/01/2021  10.93
6   100007 20/01/2021  14.05
7   100007 21/01/2021  23.27
```

O bien mediante `dplyr` puedes hacer lo mismo de una forma más explicativa:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Id_placa, Fecha) %>% 
  summarise(Litros = sum(Litros))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Id_placa [2]
  Id_placa Fecha      Litros
     <int> <chr>       <dbl>
1   100007 15/01/2021   12.6
2   100007 18/01/2021   22.7
3   100007 19/01/2021   10.9
4   100007 20/01/2021   14.0
5   100007 21/01/2021   23.3
6   100011 01/01/2021   31.6
7   100011 02/01/2021   23.1
```